# React Virtualized InfiniteLoader/Grid: How Can I Prevent Scroll Reset?

Tags: react-virtualized

I have an infinite scroll component built from React Virtualized's `InfiniteLoader` and `Grid` components.  If I scroll down using my mouse wheel (ie. reasonably slowly) everything works great.  However, when I click on the scrollbar inside the component and drag it down (moving much faster), I never make it to the bottom.  Instead, after scrolling a certain percentage of the way down the scrollbar suddenly jumps back to the top.

I've tried adding `console.log` statements in `Grid`, but all they show is that the `event.target.scrollTop` goes from a really high number one moment to `0` the next.  What I can't figure out though is why the `event.target.scrollTop` suddenly becomes `0` when all that I've done in the browser is move my mouse down (while holding the left-click button).

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix, or even just debug, this problem?

Comment: We ran into something similar while developing our DataGrid product - http://reactdatagrid.com - For us atleast, it was a result of something in our code - put a conditional breakpoint in your event handler that only hits if scrollTop is 0 and look at the call stack - may be that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be user error.

Both `InfiniteLoader` and `Grid` take a `rowCount` prop, but the two are very different values.  `InfiniteLoader` expects a `rowCount` of `numItems`, but `Grid` takes a `rowCount` of `Math.ceil(numItems/columnCount)`.  I "fixed" a separate issue by using the `InfiniteLoader` version for both, but what I really needed to do was pass different values for them.

Once I figured this out and set the two to separate values, the weird scrolling reset went away.  Despite pouring through the React Virtualized source code for quite some time though, I still can't figure out where it causes an event with a target with a `scrollTop` of `0` to occur when the `rowCount` is exceeded.  Oh well.

Comment: Both can be passed the same `rowCount` value. Your `cellRenderer` just needs to handle unloaded rows (meaning, indices that exceed your local loaded list size).

Comment: Sorry to pickup an old post @bvaughn but could you explain a little more? My cellRenderer does handle unloaded rows but I'm still running into this issue. Could this be something in the cellRangeRenderer?

Comment: Update - my issue actually seems to be connected to ArrowKeyStepper that wraps everything, it's causing the Grid to snap back to whatever the active row is when scrolling through many items at a time.